# Remove fade in in ionic loader

Tags: ionic-framework

Is it possible to remove the fade in when calling $scope.show within the ionic loader?

Ref here:
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicLoading/

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your ionic loader. Something like this:

```
$scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
        content: '<i class="icon ion-loading-c"></i>',
        animation: 'fade-in',
        showBackdrop: false,
        maxWidth: 50,
        showDelay: 0
      });


.loading {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  font-size: 15px; }
.loading h1, .loading h2, .loading h3, .loading h4, .loading h5, .loading h6 {
    color: #fff; }
```

Comment: Thanks by I already know how to style it. What's Interesting in your code is this:  animation: 'fade-in' its not documented... I tried using none but its not working, I just want the loader to show without fading in.

Comment: Ok i understand. In .loading{ .....} in ionic.css you can customize it. But it's not a good solution. I personally make changes there very carefully!